# Extract character from 2d string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, 2d

I've got 2D array of strings, so here's an example:

```
string arr[26][4];
arr[0][0] = 'A';
char t1 = arr[0][0];
```

error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char' in initialization|

What's the best way for this?

Comment: Please be specific, what does it say?

Comment: `arr` is a 1D array of string and 2D array of chars. 'A' is a `char` as well. Question is, how do you declare `arr` ?

Comment: @CuriousSid thnks, updated

Comment: @paradajz Please show the declaration of arr, it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your `arr` like this:

```
std::string arr[N][M];
```

The following works because `std::string` has an `operator=` overload that takes a `char`:

```
arr[0][0] = 'A';
```

This results in the string at position `0,0` being set to contain only `A`.

However, there is no direct conversion from a `std::string` to a `char`, as you are attempting to do in this line:

```
char temp = arr[0][0];
```

Instead, if you want the first character of the string at position `0,0`, you must do:

```
char temp = arr[0][0][0];
```

First `arr[0][0]` accesses the string at position `0,0` and then the following `[0]` accesses the first character of that string.